# How can I remove the welcome message generated by the New User Approve plugin?

Tags: plugins

I'm using the [New User Approve](http://picklewagon.com/wordpress/new-user-approve/) plugin.

After installing the plugin the top of the registration page says:

> Welcome to XXX site. This site is accessible to approved users only. To be approved, you must first register.

How can I erase this message? I'm am using this code:

```
$message = apply_filters('login_message', '');
```

But the top says still stand there!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The second argument should be a function callback, not the actual message. You can remove the message **completely** by pasting this code into your theme's `functions.php` file:

```
add_filter( 'new_user_approve_welcome_message', 'wpse_76823_login_message' );

function wpse_76823_welcome_message( $message ) {
    return '';
}
```

Or, you can replace the message by using this code:

```
add_filter( 'new_user_approve_welcome_message', 'wpse_76823_login_message' );

function wpse_76823_welcome_message( $message ) {
    return "This is my new message";
}
```

If you need more help, post a comment below.

Comment: Thank you very much,I don't know the function like sonthing add_action,add_filter,Is there a toturial?

Comment: Sorry, you provided the wrong filter hook. I've divulged the correct hook from the plugin code, see my updated answer

Comment: ok,I'm online now!

Comment: Does my answer work for you?

Comment: Yes,It works! I suppose to have something else good ...

Comment: If my answer works for you, please mark it as correct using the green tick. Thanks

Comment: how?where is the green tick?I'm new here

Comment: The green tick is to the left of my answer. Also, you may benefit from reading the [FAQ](http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/faq); it's a good way to learn more about this site

Comment: ok,I marked it.

Comment: Well,thank you very much for your enthusiasm answers,by the way ,what can the reputation of this site can do?

Comment: Have a look at http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/privileges

Comment: thanks,got it,can I we make friends ? my gtalk is :qq57842312@gtalk.com